# MySQL statement error using 'Limit'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, odbc

I'm trying to select the newest OrderID by CustomerID. But it keeps saying I have an error in my SQL syntax, even though it works in PhpMyAdmin. I'm using a `MySQL` db and an `ODBC connector`.

```
Public Function GetOrderIDByCustID(ByVal CustID As Integer) As Integer
myconn.Open()

Dim OrderID As Integer = 0
Dim OrderSQL As String = 
"SELECT OrderID 
FROM Order 
WHERE OrderCustID= ? AND OrderArchived = 0 
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC LIMIT 1"

Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("OrderSQL", myconn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OrderCustID", CustID)
OrderID= cmd.ExecuteScalar()

myconn.Close()

Return OrderID
End Function
```

So this should supply me with the OrderID of the newest Order for that Customer.

Can anyone see what I might have done wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Next time please provide the whole error message, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, I've been looking over it for an hour now ..

```
Dim cmd as New OdbcCommand("OrderSQL", myconn)
```

OrderSQL shouldn't be in brackets, solution is:

```
Dim cmd as New OdbcCommand(OrderSQL, myconn)
```

How lame lol ..